# Best way to sanitize $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']?

Tags: php, sanitization

What would be the best way to sanitize this? Would filter_var with FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING be the best bet here, or using one of the other filters?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

I know there is alot of ways of sanitizing but not sure of the best one.

Comment: Depends.  What are you doing with it?  If you are just comparing it to something else then no need.  If you are displaying it, converting to entities might be enough.

Comment: Lets assume I would be storing it in a databse.

Comment: Then we would assume you are using prepared statements to perform the inserts/updates. It would be wise to convert it to entities prior to storing this string as well because I am doubtful that PHPMyAdmin performs this for you if you are simply browsing the data.

Comment: Escape it when storing (prepared statements) and sanitize it when you display it.  Nothing worse than searching a db for things that may have been turned into entities or stripped.  Great name BTW!